# What's the difference between window.ViewName and ViewName in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

First of all, I'm a JavaScript noob and even *noober* in Backbone.js.

I'm following some online tutorials to get familiar with the technology; and while in [some tutorials](http://backbonetutorials.com/) I saw this:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        alert("Welcome to this world");
    }
});

var person = new Person;
```

In [other ones](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-2-crud/) I found this notation:

```
window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    }
});
```

What's the necessity of adding "window" to the View name? I read some [JavaScript documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) that states that the `window` object represents the current browser window, so are we adding our created view as an attribute of this object? Why is the author doing that?

Comment: They don't want to pollute the global object namespace.

Comment: @asawyer: `window` *is* the global object.

Comment: @josh3736 Major facepalm here, you are correct of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In browser JavaScript, `window` is the global object, so `window.Person === Person` unless there's a `Person` defined somewhere in the scope chain (`function() { var Person; ... }`).

In other words, there is no difference. (Other than using 7 extra characters.)

You might want to read up on [JS scope](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).  Specifically, if you assign to an otherwise undefined variable (`Person = { ... };`), that variable will be assigned to the global object (`window`).  However, if you first *declare* a variable (`var Person = { ... };`), the variable is assigned to local scope.

Comment: There is a difference to the human though. Saying `window.WineView = ...` is explicitly making it global but when I see `Person = ...`, I think someone forgot a `var` and deserves a stern talking to. So there's no difference as far as the computer is concerned but there is a big difference to the humans reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside architectural concerns (putting associated objects and properties together), global variables are handled differently from object properties if they haven't been defined. For example, assuming that the code above hasn't run and defined those objects yet, evaluating

```
Person
```

will cause a JavaScript error because it's an undefined global variable; the correct way to check if `Person` has been set is the more verbose

```
typeof Person !== 'undefined'
```

On the other hand,

```
window.WineView
```

will not cause an error but will instead return `undefined`.

Comment: This is true, but isn't really doesn't make a difference when you're *assigning* variables.